# Document referencing in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a project which uses some embeded documents and one referenced document. I choose to reference the last one because it is subject to regular updating.

Which is the best approach to displaying a document with referenced data? I've seen two approaches:

1 - Query the mongodb for the referenced data on each document
(example from http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design)

```
student.scores[0].for_course = db.courses.findOne({_id:_course_id_to_find_});
```

2 - Find the whole referenced document, cache on an object, and (on the client) match the document with its referenced data

```
db.courses.find({})
cachedCourses = {}
for course in courses {
  cachedCourses[course._id] = course //object using id as key
}
student.scores[0].for_course = cachedCourses[_course_id_to_find_]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the best approach to displaying a document with referenced data?

There is no single best approach for document referencing. Different cases serve different needs.

It will also depend on the language/framework you are using. Some frameworks provide support for seamlessly doing this lookup for you. (Morphia, MongoMapper, Mongoid to name a few)